# Does gravity change local space and time units?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, si-units

Gravity is the curvature of spacetime. Therefore, gravity affects spatial and temporal dimensions in some parts of space. We know that measuring the speed of light in the observer's local inertial frame (of his measuring devices) always equals c ≈ 3 10^8 m/s.

But could it be said that they used a local meter or a local second to measure?

c ≈ 3 10^8 local meter/local second

In other words, for different strengths of the gravitational field, there are different units of length (meters) and also different lengths of duration for the unit of time (seconds).
This also means that observers in different places with different strengths of gravitational fields will always get the same number for the speed of light, but their units of space and time will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of light is always 3x10^8 for every local Observer. That means regardless of whether you are standing on Earth or next to a black hole you will always measure using those same measurements. Because they are always true for you.

However an interesting situation occurs if for example the light was passing through a large planet. Imagine if we drilled a tunnel through the planet Venus. And a light was sent through that hole to you on Earth. That light would not hit you at the expected time because of time dilation as it passed through the planet Venus. Even if the light traveled in a straight line.

Comment: "That means regardless of whether you are standing on Earth or next to a black hole you will always measure using those same measurements. Because they are always true for you." Certainly, however, time passes more slowly near a black hole, which means that the unit of time near a black hole is longer compared to Earth. Another problem is that I wouldn't have noticed it.

Comment: Yes, as you say a unit of time near a black hole is longer than a unit of time on Earth. However let's assume that your heart beats one time per second. It will beat one time per second regardless of if you are measuring that second while you were standing near a black hole or measuring that second while you are standing on the Earth. As I said earlier for a local Observer, a second is a second. However in physics we do measure the difference between them. We just don't use different units for it.